# Custom progress dialog not showing in dialog fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, progressdialog, android-dialogfragment

**Unable to see custom progress dialog on dialog fragment**

Custom progress dialog works in Activity and Fragment but when we try to show custom progress in Dialog Fragment then loader is not showing.

Here is my code of custom dialog.

```
    /**
     * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
     */
    public class CustomAlertDialogFragment extends Dialog {
    
        /**
         * Instantiates a new Custom alert dialog fragment.
         *
         * @param context the context
         * @param text    the text
         */
        public CustomAlertDialogFragment(Context context, String text) {
                super(context, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog_NoActionBar);
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
                context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                ProgressBar v = new ProgressBar(context);
                requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                setContentView(v);
                setCancelable(false);
                getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            }
    
    }
```

And my code for showing loader is

```
     /**
         * Loading bar.
         *
         * @param enable the enable
         */
        public void loadingBar(boolean enable) {
            if (enable) {
    
                if (progressDialog == null) {
                    progressDialog = new CustomAlertDialogFragment(getActivity(), "");
                }
                if (!progressDialog.isShowing())
                    progressDialog.show();
            } else {
                dismissProgressBar();
            }
        }
    
        /**
         * Dismiss progress bar.
         */
        public void dismissProgressBar() {
            if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
    
        }
```

I am calling loader as

```
    loadingBar(true);
    File source = new File("/mnt/extSdCard/Audio"); 
    File dest = new File("/mnt/UsbDriveA/Dokita");
    copyDirectory(source, dest);
    loadingBar(false);
```

Comment: I think you need to use progressDialog.show()

Comment: After editing your question from progressDialog.create() to .show() .. still now working ?

Comment: still not working

Comment: Try debugging your code and make sure that debugger entered to progressDialog.show()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are running long running tasks(which should be done in background) in a Thread or with an AsyncTask

Implement the code below in your app

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        loadingBar(true);
        File source = new File("/mnt/extSdCard/Audio"); // source of file
        File dest = new File("/mnt/UsbDriveA/Dokita"); // destination of file
        copyDirectory(source, dest);
        loadingBar(false);
    }
};
copyDirectory(source, dest); 
thread.start();
```

Comment: i have tried above solution and working well. so thanks for help me to solve issue